# Elastic search : no configured node available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am running following code which will try to pull data from database and index it using elastic search.
Data volumn in around 1 million records.
But code breaks somewhere in middle and gives error as "**no configured node available**".
Also, even if code runs without error it does not load entire data.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                                .build();

Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
                            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));

while(rs.next())
{
    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();   
    json.put("id", rs.getLong("id"));
    json.put("type",rs.getString("type"));      
    client.prepareIndex("test", "doc").setSource(json).execute();
}
```

Thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: What's with the `<pre>` tags?

Comment: Most probably, you are overloading the cluster. The nodes start to run out of memory/CPU and dies.

Comment: how can i stop cluster from overloading...actually it takes up all my RAM and then i have to kill it

Comment: Don't send so many/so large indexing requests to it. Definitely is not able to support that and you are reaching its limits. Or get a more powerful cluster.

Comment: but that's not always the case, even if i send small amount of data. It still gives No configured nodes available.

Comment: out of memory happens less number of times considering this error

Comment: Then you are still overloading the cluster. Elasticsearch can do wonders for searching, but don't use a RaspberryPI to store an ES node and then expect to handle hundreds of searches per second or index 10000 documents per second.

Comment: I have tried loading data in small chunks and it works. It does not give error and runs for all data provided. But for final count which should be 50k its giving 44k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you are overloading the cluster. The nodes start to run out of memory/CPU and dies. Don't send so many/so large indexing requests to it. Definitely is not able to support that and you are reaching its limits. Or get a more powerful cluster.

Have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big) for details on how to size your chunk of messages:

> The entire bulk request needs to be loaded into memory by the node that receives our request, so the bigger the request, the less memory available for other requests. There is an optimal size of bulk request. Above that size, performance no longer improves and may even drop off. The optimal size, however, is not a fixed number. It depends entirely on your hardware, your document size and complexity, and your indexing and search load.
>
> Fortunately, it is easy to find this sweet spot: Try indexing typical documents in batches of increasing size. When performance starts to drop off, your batch size is too big. A good place to start is with batches of 1,000 to 5,000 documents or, if your documents are very large, with even smaller batches.
>
> It is often useful to keep an eye on the physical size of your bulk requests. One thousand 1KB documents is very different from one thousand 1MB documents. A good bulk size to start playing with is around 5-15MB in size.